# How to use SET with SELECT DISTINCT

Tags: mysql, sql, select, distinct

I have a table:

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `pn` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `price` int(1) NOT NULL,
  `company` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `flag` varchar(1) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

What I want to do is to find cheapest goods (pn) and I've managed to do it:

```
SELECT DISTINCT min(price), pn, company FROM `test` GROUP BY pn
```

But how I can also mark cheapest goods with flag. I want for all the results Update tabel, set flag=1.
How to do that? **Is it possible to use UPDATE table with SELECT DISTINCT?**

Here is a SQL Fiddle:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ea1b3f/9

Comment: That query is invalid. Won't execute on newer MySQL versions (unless in compatibility mode), may return unpredictable results with older MySQL versions. The general GROUP BY rule says: If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function!

Comment: You should go for: `UPDATE <your table> SET flag = 'Y' WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID FROM (<your original query>))`.

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result, both for the SELECT and for the UPDATE. (Formatted text, not images.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, `select distinct` with `group by` is almost never the right thing to do.  Presumably, you intend something like:

```
SELECT min(price), pn, min(company)
FROM `test`
GROUP BY pn;
```

If you want to set a flag for all the min prices, use a join:

```
update test t join
       (select pn, min(price) as minprice
        from test
        group by pn
       ) tt
       on t.pn = tt.pn and t.price = tt.minprice
    set t.flag = 1;
```

Comment: First SELECT doesn't work as expected. Always shows producer1 - please check on SQL fiddle. Possibly min(company) ?

Comment: @tikky `company1` is the lowest company for each `pn`.

Comment: @Tikky That query isn't supposed to return the company name for the lowest price. For that, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745609/sql-select-only-rows-with-max-value-on-a-column?rq=1

Comment: @barmar "company1 is the lowest company for each pn" - not exacly. For pn "ram" cheapest company it is "company2", please see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ea1b3f/9 And I need the company also (or id from chepaest source)

Comment: @Gordon Linoff - can I use 'company' instead of min(company)?

Comment: @Tikky min(company) is not the cheapest company, it's the lowest company name. Read the linked question to see how to get the cheapest company.

Comment: @Tikky . . . This question is about prices.  Nothing in the question is about "company".  If you have another question, then ask it as a new *question*.

Comment: @GordonLinoff thank you for the answer. Yes, I suppose to add information about producer in question also. Sorry for not clear question.